# $W(\gamma +v , p+ v) = W(\gamma, p)$ why is this true?

Tags: winding-number

I don't understand why this statement in lecture is true :

> let $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \left \{  p\right \} $ a continuous path, and v any vector in the plane. Moreover, let $\gamma$ +v be the path defined by 
> $(\gamma + v)(t) = \gamma(t) + v $
> it follows that 
> $W(\gamma +v , p+ v) = W(\gamma, p)$  
> in this sense we say that winding numbers are invariant under translation.

But why does this follow? Do I have to use some Linear Algebra to get there ?
Could someone maybe explain to me why this statement is true ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: $\gamma+v$ intuitivly is just the translation of the curve along a vector. It has no affect to the curvature of $\gamma$.  The winding number is given as the total curvature of a closed curve over $2\pi$. Since the curvature remains the same under such translation the total curvature is also the same, hence the winding number is the same aswell.

Comment: thank you very much! this makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifying $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$ in the natural way:\begin{eqnarray*}W(\gamma +v , p+ v) &=&\frac1{2\pi i}\int_a^b \frac1{(\gamma+v)t-(p+v)}\frac{d(\gamma+v)}{dt}dt\\
&=&\frac1{2\pi i}\int_a^b \frac1{\gamma(t)-p}\frac{d\gamma}{dt}dt\\
 &=&W(\gamma, p)\end{eqnarray*}